# How to access file paths in Twig

Tags: php, image, loops, twig

I need to get the file path to images in a directory and output them as the `src=""` in the image. I've attempted to set a variable as the images directory, and then created a loop to run over each item in the directory.

Example:

```
  {% set files = "/images/case-study/study-thumbnails/" %}
  {% for image in files %}
    <div class="project">
      <a href=""><img src="{{ image }}"></a>
    </div
  {% endfor %}
```

I know I'm probably way off on this but I'm pretty new to Twig and have been lost in this for hours now.

Comment: That snippet is basically trying to iterate the string "files". You need to extend twig and write a function that gets and returns all files in that path so you can iterate through them: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#functions

Comment: I think you should get the collection of files in your controller and pass that to the view. This seems like you're trying to get the view to do something that isn't really its job.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to try and move all that logic to the Controller instead of the view. Then, you won't get a file pointer just by assigning a string path name in Twig. That won't work.

What I'd recommend you is processing all these images paths in the Controller, and storing them in an array. And then you pass this array to the Twig view. Then you'll be free to handle this array in the Twig file.